# Somatorio Jasper iReport

Tags: ireport, jasper

Bom dia,

Estou com um problema para somar registros no ireport, no final da minha pagina coloquei a variavel PAGE_COUNT, porem ele só soma os registros da ultima pagina.
Como fazer para somar os registros de todas as paginas?

Desde ja agradeço

Comment: PAGE_COUNT não seria para contar páginas?

Comment: Não, a função que conta paginas chama PAGE_NUMBER

Comment: Pesquisando, descobri que PAGE_COUNT é o numero de registros processados a partir do inicio da página. Portanto essa váriavel irá ter sempre o número de registros da ultima pagina processada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para saber o número total de registros use a `$V{REPORT_COUNT}` e configure a avaliação para "Report". Para ocorrer apenas no final do relatório.

Comment: Valeu era isso mesmo, muito Obrigado